# Post request work with one collection but not with the another using mongodb nodejs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, postman

I am trying to build a simple rest api. Firstly, I have 2 collections books and genres. once I post using postman in genres it post with no problems but once I post into books collection the post requesting time take about 2 minutes(which consider too much) then it return with connection error with knowing the server is remain working.

app

```
// Tools to be used in the web development
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

app.use(bodyParser.json());


Genre = require('./models/genre.js');
Book = require('./models/book.js');



let conn = mongoose.connection;
conn.openUri('mongodb://localhost/bookstore');

conn.on('error', err => console.error('mongodb connection error', 
err));
conn.on('connected', () => console.info(`Connected to mongodb`));
conn.on('disconnected', () => console.info('Disconnected from 
mongodb'));


// Routing to specific pages:
app.get('/', function(req, res){
res.send('Hello World');
});

app.get('/api/genres', function(req , res){
Genre.getGenres(function(err, genres){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genres);
})
});

app.get('/api/books', function(req , res){
Book.getBooks(function(err, books){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(books);
})
});

app.get('/api/books/:_id', function(req , res){
Book.getBookById(req.params._id, function(err, book){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(book);
})
});

app.post('/api/genres', function(req , res){
var genre = req.body;
Genre.addGenre(genre, function(err, genre){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(genre);
})
});

app.post('/api/books', function(req , res){
var book = req.body;
Book.addBook(function(err, book){
    if(err){
        throw err;
    }
    res.json(book);
})
});


//Specify the listening port
app.listen(3666);
//Display the url on the termianl
console.log('Server Running On http://localhost:3666');
```

Book

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

//Book Schema
var bookSchema = mongoose.Schema({

title:{
    type: String,
    requires: true
},
genre:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
description:{
    type: String
},
author:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
publisher:{
    type: String,
    required: true
},
create_date:{
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
}
});

var Book = module.exports = mongoose.model('Book', bookSchema);

module.exports.getBooks = function(callback, limit){
Book.find(callback).limit(limit);

}


module.exports.getBookById = function(id, callback){
Book.findById(id, callback);

}

//add genre
module.exports.addBook = function(book, callback){
Book.create(book, callback);
}
```

and [the postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nmiU7.png)

and [database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FVo0Y.png)

Notice: once I post request in genres I works but once I post for the book nothing happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `addBook` function takes two parameters: a `book` object and a callback

```
//add genre
module.exports.addBook = function(book, callback){
    Book.create(book, callback);
}
```

But, while calling it, you have only passed a callback. You can try to use the below code:

```
app.post('/api/books', function(req , res){
    var book = req.body;
    Book.addBook(book, function(err, book){
      if(err){
         throw err;
      }
      res.json(book);
    })
});
```